# Ajax tabs are not loading javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using [this](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/) ajax tabs. 
i am using a javascript in the content.htm but its not working. 
this is my code.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#content").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#content {
    background:khaki;
    padding:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">This is a paragraph.</div>

<button>Toggle slideUp() and slideDown()</button>
```

Comment: your code is missing jquery include I guess

Comment: its ajax base tabs so there is no head,body tags. this is plain content.htm file. although its loading css properly.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: no there is no error but toggle is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! 
Simply i fetch content as iframe... now js working properly.